# importing PyCrypto Library is not working in Python3

Tags: python, cryptography

`from Crypto.Cipher import AES`

This gives me following error when executed with python3. It works fine in python2.

> > ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'

What is problem here?

Comment: Have you installed it for python3?

Comment: Does it have to be installed seperately for python3? How to do it then?

Comment: your comment gave me an hint, got the solution now. Posted the answer. thanks @thebjorn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this:
The pycrypto library has to be installed using pip3 instead of pip.

> sudo pip3 install crypto;
>
> sudo pip3 install pycrypto

Import works fine afterwords.